# How to downgrade all installed packages from LP-PPA-ubuntu-toolchain-r-test

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa

I am not able to upgrade Ubuntu 16.04 to 17.10 due to issues with packages which I installed from LP-PPA-ubuntu-toolchain-r-test. These packages are numerous... Is there a way (using some tool or script) that automatically downgrades packages that are newer than official Ubuntu release?

Comment: ppa-purge is the tool you're looking for

Comment: My question is why do you want to upgrade to 17.10 when it goes EOL in less than 2 days and will no longer be supported?  You can wait till the 26th when 18.04.1 gets released and that is when 16.04 LTS should start prompting for the upgrade.

Comment: Unfortunately I urgently needed to upgrade to 18.04 from 16.04 and thought going via 17.10 would solve the issue. Using ppa-purge solved my issues and was able to directly upgrade 16.04 to 18.04.